# this.location not passing json arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a form in a page named search1.html, when the form clicks submit it calls a function on a Java Script, This Java script then generate a Json string with the input from the form. Then It should Reload the same page search1.html passing the Json string as an argument but it's not passing the argument. Here is my code:

```
var $keyword = $('#keyword').val();
var $searchString = '';
$searchString = encodeURI('searchString={"keyword": "' + $keyword +  '"}');
$newUrl="http://domain/search1.html?"+$searchString;
console.log($newUrl);
this.location = $newUrl;
```

as an example, if keyword is "pizza" in thhe console.log I get the correct output:

```
domain/search1.html?searchString={%22keyword%22:%20%22pizza%22}
```

in firefox it loads the page with no arguments as: `domain/search1.html` 
in chrome it loads it as `domain/search1.html?` with nothing after the `?`

If i change this line:

```
$newUrl="domain/search1.html?"+$searchString;
```

to anything else, example:

```
$newUrl="domain/anything.html?"+$searchString;
```

It does work perfectly fine..

Anyone has a clue why this is happening?

Comment: if you paste the URL from the console log into the address bar directly, does it work?

Comment: yes, if I copy paste the URL from the console log to the address bar it does work

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue you are dealing with is that you cannot encode the equals sign when passing a query parameter. The solution I propose is to build a json object instead of having to encode a query parameter:

```
var json = {'keyword':$('#keyword').val()};
window.location.href = "http://domain/search1.html?searchString="+JSON.stringify(json);
```

> **Proof of concept**

```
<button onclick='submit()'>Submit</button>
<script>
function submit() {
    var json = {'keyword':'stackoverflow'};
    window.open("?searchString="+JSON.stringify(json));
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion as well, but I experience the same results. as I posted, the $newUrl in the console.log does have a valid URL and if you click it work, but the window.location.href wont pass parameter. It's even more interesting that  even if i'm hardcoding ` "http://domain/search1.html?searchString=" ` it does not load with the "?searchString=" part

Comment: @daniel, I put a proof of concept to show that at its simplest, it will work. So something else is probably causing the problem. Do a small scale experiment. Maybe try ````window.open```` like above

Comment: good suggestion, I used the window.open instead of the this.location or windows.location.href command in my code and it works perfectly fine. Definitely something strange is going on with this

Comment: @daniel Interesting. Does it work if you type this in the console? ````window.location="http://domain/search1.html?searchString={keyword:pizza}";````